# Sending post data with Query sting as url

Tags: jquery

I am making a little website and need to send data via `$.post`
but I have a little problem my link looks like `admin.php?user`

Right now the Code looks like this

```
$.post("admin.php?menu",{action: "up", ids: id, type: type},function(msg) {
        alert(msg);
});
```

But the code is returning the html code

What can I do that $.post accepts Query Strings

Comment: Nothing (except possibly your own server side code which you haven't shared with us) prevents you from using a query string on a URL for a POST request.

Comment: If it returns HTML code then that is because your server side code is designed to do that (or it has bugs).

Comment: Your menu should have a value, like this: "admin.php?menu=foobar"

Answer (score 0):

Her how i build the link

```
class menu {
function getMenu($where = 0) {
$url = explode('&',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
if($where == 0) {
 if(file_exists('modul/'$url[0].'.php') {
   return $url[0];
 }
} elseif($where == 1) {
if(file_exists('admin/modul/'$url[0].'.php') {
   return $url[0];
 }
}

}
}
```

in the index.php or admin.php i include the modul

With this my link looks like http://domain/admin.php?filename or http://domain/index.php?filename

Forgot to say what i want to do :(

Right now iam making it posible to change the Menu Pos

```
<table>
<tr> 
<td>{MENU}</td>
<td><a href="javascript:moveUp('{id}','{type}');">Up</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In Php i checking if action == moveup

```
if(isset($_POST['moveup'])) {
    $m = "prefix_menu";
    $p = "pos";
    if($_POST['type'] == "cat") {
        $m = "prefix_menukat";
        $p = "cpos";
    }
    $erg = db_query("UPDATE `$m` SET `$p`=$p-1 WHERE `id`='{$_POST['id']}'");
    if($erg) {
        echo "Pos changed";
    }
}
```

and in jquery i just send the post like this

```
<script>
    function moveup(id,type) {
        $.post("admin.php?menu",{action: "moveup", ids: id, type: type},function(msg) {
            alert(msg);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is i need to send it over the Query String because of my loader.php witch is loading all needed functions like database connection a while ago i found a function that would allow to send data over query string i think it was on stackoverflow but iam not sure about it and can*t find it anymore :(